# JavaScript - Multiple buttons to input into its own text box on same page

Tags: javascript

I am using caspio as a platform to produce a 9 question assessment, each of the questions has 5 possible answers that are clickable for the user. if they click an answer once they get an answer between m1 - m5, if they click the same answer again it will give them m1+ - m5+. I have this working for the top question. But when I tried to add in the rest of the questions they are all updating  the first question textbox.

I'm not a proficient coder, I'm just a googler (if there is such a word!) - which has got me thus far. Any help will be greatly appreciated

The code below is for the top question which works fine:

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tbody>

  <tr>
   <td>Question 1: Condition and appearance of buildings, internal &amp; external grounds, parking areas and roadways.</td>
   <td id="m1" class="box" >Condition and appearance are poor with no defined standards</td>
   <td id="m2" class="box">Appearance and condition generally average and numerous issues seen on plant tour</td>
   <td id="m3" class="box">Appearance and condition generally good but a number of issues seen on plant tour</td>
   <td id="m4" class="box">Appearance and condition generally very good but some minor issues seen on plant tour</td>
   <td id="m5" class="box">Excellent appearance and condition with no major issues</td>
   
 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script>
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('InsertRecordQuestion1');   
  
//Get all the boxes
        var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
        //Loop through the boxes
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            //Add an event to each box
            boxes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                //Get the id of the box
                var elementId = e.target.id;
                //Check if the box has the class 'selected'
                if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    //Change the class to 'double-selected'
                    this.classList.remove('selected');
                    this.classList.add('double-selected');
                    //Output the double selected value
          outputDiv.textContent = elementId + '+';
          document.getElementById('InsertRecordQuestion1').value = outputDiv.textContent;   
                } else {
                    //Loop through the boxes
                    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                        //Remove the 'selected' class from each box
                        boxes[i].classList.remove('selected');
                        boxes[i].classList.remove('double-selected');
                    }
                    //Add the 'selected' class to the current box
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                    //Output the value of the selected box
                outputDiv.textContent = elementId;
                document.getElementById('InsertRecordQuestion1').value = outputDiv.textContent
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```